# How do you nest if statement in do-while loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

```js
var temp = 110;
for {
    temp-=1
    if (temp >= 90) {
        console.log("Today's temperature is "+temp+"! "+"Lets go play ball")
    } else {
        console.log("Today's temperature is "+temp+"! "+"It is too hot today to ball!")
    }
    
}while (temp > 90)
```

Please review my snippet. It won't run for some reason stating some bracket error as I already checked the brackets.

Comment: You're using for wrongly. Replace it to do.

Comment: Replace `for` with `do`

Comment: I have a question for you! If you are asking the user for a prompt, you shouldn't be using a while loop because, that will make your loop go on forever.

Comment: I see. Sorry for my ignorance. I just want to see how to implement it...sooner or later i will realize by myself the letting user prompt the code was a mistake. =\ thank you for your advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The do while loop syntax is like this:

**Example**

```
do {

}while(conditions);
```

So a do-while loop with a nested if/else statement is like this:

**do-while w/ nested if/else**

```
do{

if() {
}
else {
}
}while();
```

**Example w/ YOUR CODE**

var temp = 110;

```
do {
 if(temp >= 90) 
{
    console.log("Today's temperature is "+temp+"! "+"Lets go play ball");
{
else 
{
    console.log("Today's temperature is "+temp+"! "+"It is too hot today to play      ball!");
}
 temp--; 
} while(temp > 90);
```

Okay now, let me explain what is happening here. What you are essentially doing is telling the compiler to do something until the while loop returns true. So, if you notice I changed `temp -= 1;` `to temp--;` it is exactly the samething it's just much more standard to use the latter. You were actually very close with your original code other than it is a do-while loop not a for-while. :)

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed explanation! if there a way to revise the code that only display the console.log of the specified temp the user put in?

Comment: Yeah just output the users input. `var sample = prompt("Input Temp");` Then print out the users input like this, `console.log(sample);`

Comment: Make sure to mark this as the answer, it helps me out and others! :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? That way I can write out a code that is specific to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I wanted to `console.log` one or the other of the if statement. however, it displaying all the iterations of `console.log`. then I realize it is suppose to show since it did in a loop function. Problem solved thank you for your time!

Comment: Well, but you could just use if/else statements instead of nesting them. It will show the iteration because it is within the scope of the do-while statement.

Answer (score 2):

Its `do` not `for`

```js
var temp = 110;
do { //its `do` not `for`
  temp -= 1;
  if (temp >= 90) {
    console.log("Today's temperature is " + temp + "! " + "Lets go play ball")
  } else {
    console.log("Today's temperature is " + temp + "! " + "It is too hot today to ball!")
  }

} while (temp > 90);
```

You may use `prompt()` for user input:

```js
var temp = prompt('Input temperature', '110'); // (message, default input)
console.log('temp', temp);
do { //its `do` not `for`
  temp -= 1;
  if (temp >= 90) {
    console.log("Today's temperature is " + temp + "! " + "Lets go play ball")
  } else {
    console.log("Today's temperature is " + temp + "! " + "It is too hot today to ball!")
  }

} while (temp > 90);
```

Comment: Thank you! now is there a way to only display one temp Prompt(ing) the user temperature?

Comment: thank you for your hastily update! Is there a way to only control.log the  prompt temp?

Answer (score 1):

Replace for with do. like this

```
var temp = 110;
do{
    temp-=1
    if (temp >= 90) {
        console.log("Today's temperature is "+temp+"! "+"Lets go play ball")
    } else {
        console.log("Today's temperature is "+temp+"! "+"It is too hot today to ball!")
    }

}while (temp > 90)
```

Comment: Thank you! now is there a way to only display one temp Prompt(ing) the user temperature?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```js
var temp = 110;
do {
    temp-=1
    if (temp >= 90) {
        console.log("Today's temperature is "+temp+"! "+"Lets go play ball")
    } else {
        console.log("Today's temperature is "+temp+"! "+"It is too hot today to ball!")
    }
    
}while (temp > 90);
```